# How to make play and pause button on Google Vr video

Tags: google-vr

I add 360 video to website and I want to add button for play and pause.
I have following code for my Video. 
I very appreciate for help.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener('load', onVrViewLoad);
var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
 width: '100%',
 height: 400,
    video: 'german.mp4',
 is_stereo: false,
  });
}
</script>
```

```html
<html>

<script src="//storage.googleapis.com/vrview/2.0/build/vrview.min.js"></script>

<div id="vrview"></div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want to play video success, you have to do this:

1. Don't use the script from
   `storage.googleapis.com/vrview/2.0/build/vrview.min.js`.
2. Download the sample zip and use the script : `vrview-master/build/vrview.js`.

Second, you want to have buttons for play and pause, see the sample zip, you need link style.css, and have the correct path in style.css, like below.

```
background: url('vrview-master/examples/img/ic_pause_black_24dp.svg');
```

Comment: @VPK Thank you very much

Comment: @Joe I'm not sure why are you thanking me, I've just edited the answer. If this answer solved your problem, accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', onVrViewLoad)
let veView;
function onVrViewLoad() {
  vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
    video: '//vr.jwplayer.com/content/AgqYcfAT/AgqYcfAT-8yQ1cYbs.mp4',
    width: '300',
    height: '180'
  });
}
function play(){
  vrView.play()
}
function pause(){
  vrView.pause()
}
function mute(){
  vrView.setVolume(0)
}
function unmute(){
  vrView.setVolume(1)
}
```

```html
<script src="//storage.googleapis.com/vrview/2.0/build/vrview.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="vrview"></div>
  <button type="button"  onclick="play()">Play</button>
  <button type="button"  onclick="pause()">Pause</button>
  <button type="button"  onclick="mute()">Mute</button>
  <button type="button"  onclick="unmute()">UnMute</button>
</body>
```

Comment: hi buddy could you please help me in this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49166181/control-button-on-google-vr-view